# Fixed height and internal scrolling for expanablelistview

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview

I have an expandable listview, which is populated programatically. i want to have fixed length for that expandable listview and have scrolling inside each group not for the whole list.

my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_price_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/theme_blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pricelisthead_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="PRICING"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pricelisthead_np"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="NORMAL"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_pricelisthead_ep"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="EXPRESS"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--
 android:background="@drawable/hf_bg"  
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price_list"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Price List"/>
    -->

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_pricelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

with the above layout i could get a list view.
i want this listview to occupy fixed length. headers should always be shown and scrolling should be there for internal child items not for the whole list.
i have only 3 groups and each group may have around 10-30 child items.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code on SO a while back, i tried searching for this, but couldn't find it. If someone does, please edit my answer and provide link to the original answer. Since `ExpandableListView` extends `ListView` you can use this code, but make sure in your adapter that the children are expanded already.

```
private void justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = listView.getLayoutParams();
        par.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(par);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but my list stopped scrolling after adding this code

Comment: Put your `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView` and this will work.